# How to require FileUpload with actual upload, not just selecting a file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, validation, upload

I have a FileUpload control along with a required field validator. It throws an error if the user doesn't click the Browse button to select a file (which is correct). However, if the user clicks the Browse button, but doesn't click the Upload button, ASP.NET's required validator doesn't throw an error. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, do you mean you want it validated when a user does not choose a file when he clicked Browse? If thats the case the required field validatoe wont trigger until you hit upload

Comment: I just want to force the user to upload a file attachment when they submit "an application". Users can bypass my required field validator by clicking on the Browse button of the file upload control, selecting a file, and then submitting the "application" without ever clicking the Upload button of the file upload control. I want to close this loophole. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a CustomValidator instead of a RequiredFieldValidator?

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength != 0;
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            var myFileName = "somefile.jpg"
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(myFileName);
        }
    }
```